# A question about a sentence using a past tense

Tags: sentence-construction, subjunctives

I tried to write a sentence like the following.

> I have thought that I were similar to the older man after seeing him.

I wonder if it is grammatically correct and idiomatic, or conveys a subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 1):

The given sentence

> (A) I have thought that I were similar to the older man after seeing him.

is not grammatically correct, and is not in the subjunctive mood.

First of all it does not agree in number. "I" is singular, so the singular form "was" must be used, not the plural form "were". It is true that a verb in the subjunctive often uses "were" when "was" would otherwise be proper, but this is not such a case. No wish, imagined situation or suggestion is present here.

A grammatical subjunctive form might be:

> (B) After I saw the older man, I wished that I were like him.

In form B the "were" (together with the verb "wish") shows that the subjunctive is being used, and that the speaker is **not** "like the older man" and the wish is for an unreal situation, one that does not exist. Two  parallel but non-subjunctive sentences might be:

> (C1) After I saw the older man, I thought that I was like him.
> (C2) After I saw the older man, I wished that I was like him, and indeed I was.

In both C1 and C2 the speaker **is** like the older man, and "was" is used, not "were".  In C2 the speaker seems to think that s/he is **not** like the older man, but later thinks otherwise, so the subjunctive is not used.

Comment: If "that I were" is changed to "as if I were", can it convey a subjunctive mood?

Comment: @bak193 that cannot be usefully answered without the whole sentence. In which of the sentences in the question or answer do you want to make such a change, or in what other sentence(s).  "as if I were" can be part of a subjunctive construction, but it isn't always.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not grammatically correct.  "that I **were**" does not make sense here; you would only use "I were" in a subjunctive context like "If I were", but I don't see any subjunctive here.  You simply thought that you were like the old man.

Also, I am not sure what past tense you are referring to, because "I have thought" is the **present** perfect, not the past!  (To see the difference, think about other uses of *to have*: "I *have* two cats": present tense.  "I *had* two cats": past tense.)

Finally, the sentence is not completely fluent or understandable.  It sounds like:

- you saw the older man
- after that, you thought you were similar to him

You can use "I have thought" here, but using the present perfect implies something particular, because "after seeing him, I thought" sounds like you saw him one time, and "after seeing him, I have thought" sounds like you are describing a repeated occurrence.

"After seeing the older man, I thought I was similar to him" sounds like you saw him once and then had the thought.

"After seeing the older man, I have thought that I was similar to him" sounds like you have seeing him and had the thought more than once.